# R data.table assigning single-row list-type columns

Tags: r, data.table

I find the logic of `data.table` inconsistent for the two below operations:

Operation 1:

```
df1<-data.table(a=c(1,2))
list1<-list(c(1,2), 1)
df1[,b:=list1]

#> df1
#   a   b
#1: 1 1,2
#2: 2   1
```

Operation 2: (data.table treats a singleton list as if I supplied a vector)

```
df2<-data.table(a=c(1))
list2<-list(c(1,2))
df2[, b:=list2]
#Warning message:
#In `[.data.table`(df2, , `:=`(b, list2)) :
#  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'b' (1 unused)
#> df2
   a b
#1: 1 1
```

I would like the output in the second case to be:

```
#   a   b
#1: 1 1,2
```

I can do to unify both cases:

```
df1[, b:=list(list1)]
df2[, b:=list(list2)]
```

Is this the best solution? Is there no option for data.table to not unnest a singleton list? Are there no extra operations performance-wise in the first case when I use `b:=list(list1)`?

Comment: Related: [data.table add list as column when only one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054302/data-table-add-list-as-column-when-only-one-row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54797914/2490497
I cannot suggests a duplicate because of "This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer
".

---

This is very good question that touches design decision about `:=` operator.

For simple calls using `:=` as an operator, like `col := val`, we decided to wrap `val` into a list automatically. This decision was made to make it more convenient for users to assign single column.

When you are using function call form, `":="(col = val)` we are not wrapping `val` into list anymore. It is extended form already. `:=` behaves as an alias to `list` but updating *in-place*. You can always check what will be the updated column by changing `:=` into `list` (or `.`) like `.(col = val)`.

Not that even when using `:=` as an operator, you still have to provide RHS as list of you are creating 2+ columns, `c("col1","col2") := list(val1, val2)`.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question how to unify the cases (use the functional form ':='). Saying that you automatically wrap to list when we have `col := val` does not explain my examples though: perhaps you wrap if val is *not* already a list, maybe you could add this to documentation.